# How to obtain list of Music Sources from the Sonos household?

Tags: sonos

I am trying to get a list of music services to which the Sonos household has a subscription. Is it possible to obtain such information from HTTP API or from any other source? If yes, then under what conditions?

I have analyzed the traffic between the Sonos Connect and Windows Sonos Controller. I discover, that information about music services is transmitted from Connect to Controller inside the ThirdPartyMediaServersX tag of the NOTIFY HTTP request. But this content is encoded in the base64-like cipher.

```xml
<e:propertyset xmlns:e="urn:schemas-upnp-org:event-1-0">
<e:property>
<ThirdPartyMediaServersX>
2:oZoYgaU5pqEq6IauQ1hYVS0oCUJnqbCkJL1vXP/DoeijejEwUBQT8UG0CksUG9VcarvLhCyElhKTUjfhQt0SAcV2oBOyLJ5BCmjd7TcJfPrVuTGHczd5/AS2tgj85n0U9yU9EwwHROFb5uV09syZNLVaZuJnENCWRKatIq1SNMm1SE4tHneLG6ULQoDOR50nf7TwyRQbkit8Bvy+kZyNPlrgBZFGmizoRmYjW8COFvHJpZhREEGruhQ2J6A8gnQOWyFzstAyHNZeLqp2xcNGnts6f2DQ56r/ducstbibFH0SZOZC0XM/BB4DvOT8UalezPL0R9/s8Jibm5T6mS1FWk14GWg2RMmRBIVE5G/gG2c=
</ThirdPartyMediaServersX>
</e:property>
</e:propertyset>
```

I expect to obtain list of music services, but the actual list were hidden.

Comment: great question @Igor

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, Sonos disabled this functionality some time ago.

I've spend a lot of time figuring out how it works, and I now have a "work-a-round". [External music services](https://svrooij.io/sonos-api-docs/music-services.html) describes what to do.

And [sonos-ts](https://svrooij.io/node-sonos-ts/) has support for [external music services](https://svrooij.io/node-sonos-ts/sonos-device/external-music-services.html). If you read my first link and check the code in this library you should probably be able to figure out how to do that in your programming language.

I know this is no access to the list that is kept by Sonos, but this work-a-round also saves the tokens on the device for every client application to use.

Recently I've found someone who build an [music service emulator](https://github.com/simojenki/bonob). So that are both sides of external music services.

Answer (score -1):

This is not supported by the Sonos API.

Comment: The Sonos app is not the best (or the fastest). So this seems like a good question. I'm also investigating the protocol, and if you (Sonos) don't want to help the proces will only take longer, but since the app communicates with the speakers in plain text it should be possible to find out the needed data.